# What is the meaning of the official transcript?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, transcript-of-records

I am going to apply for graduate admission in the US universities. Most of the universities require official transcript  which  must be sent from my institute with official envelope and seal.

**I went to my university to send the offical transcript to the US universities. The controller of the examiner asked me that which one I want. New transcript or copy of my transcript verified by the controller with envelope seal.**

More precisely, they asked me to give them photocopy of my original transcript. After I give them the copy, they will sign and pul offcial seal to send to the university I wanted to send.

My question is that,,

> will the US universities consider the  copy of the main transcripts(verified by the exam controller with enveloped and seal) as official?

or

> US universities  are expecting original transcripts (with seal and
>   enveloped) like I have a copy with me?

Comment: I would think either would be okay.

Comment: If I want to get the original one from my department (like the one I have) they will give but it requires a lot of verification and it takes time too.

Comment: We can't really answer... ask directly. If in doubt, send the not-so-official one, and promise to send the one with seal and signature and notarized by the embassy and all later.

Comment: I think we can't really answer AND that likely either is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is about graduate admission, universities normally require an official transcript (i.e. NOT a copy). An official transcript normally carries the signature of the Registrar, is in color, and is put in an sealed envelop prepared by the Registrar's office.

Some US universities require that your transcript comes directly from the Registrar's office of your institution, while some would accept one that you send in as long as it's inside the sealed envelop prepared by the registrar's office.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your incoming school to accept your official transcript, it must be ordered from your previous school and must be sealed. They will not accept photographs, copies, open transcript packages. Contact your department of student affairs.

"will the US universities consider the copy of the main transcripts(verified by the exam controller with enveloped and seal) as official?"

Your school has an administration dedicated to supervising the transfer of international students. My educated guess is yes, it will be acceptable. Contact your student affairs department for more information.

Comment: You write as though this is a universal condition for all schools: is this in fact the case?